# How to build a custom filter in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a few entries like this:

```
Name  Manager  Boss
Guy1  A        X
Guy2  B        X
Guy3  X        X
```

I have used Manager column as a filter. But, my requirement is that when someone filters by selecting X from the Manager, all the 3 entries should be displayed, since X is the boss.
How can I achieve this? Should I use a custom column or a measure to achieve the same?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Use just [Boss] column as filter (slicer) or add more accurate example :)

Comment: There is only 1 value for Boss i.e X, but X can be a manager as well. If you select X in the filter, all of the rows should be displayed

Comment: Create additional table with all your Manager (WITHOUT relationship) and put this into slicer. Next create a measure on your main table and put it on visual. In my case 'Table_' is my slicer.

Filter = if(SELECTEDVALUE('Table_'[Manager]) = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Manager]) || SELECTEDVALUE('Table_'[Manager]) = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Boss]), 1, BLANK())

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution you're looking for is just to have an additional filter for Boss, or to create a hierarchy where they can select overall boss or drill down to specific managers.

A lengthy solution involves manipulating the manager field to - essentially - NOT work when filtered to a certain selection. You could do this by having a calculated table that takes in your input of manager - if X is selected, do nothing. If A is selected, filter to A.

Again I think this situation is better addressed as a hierarchy or a redesign of the data structure. If X is the only boss you are expecting throughout the dataset you could just direct users to use "Select All". But I imagine this isn't the case